# Pasting into a Hyper-V VM in enhanced mode

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, hyper-v, clipboard

I presume I'm missing something really obvious here - I have a Hyper-V VM.  In basic mode, I can copy, and then select "Type Clipboard Text", and in Enhanced Mode I can just copy and paste as normal - except on the windows sign-in screen (in basic mode, "Type Clipboard Text" works wherever I am).

I'm managing all my VM passwords using a password manager, and just want to be able to paste the password in from the host machine, but it won't let me copy / paste until I'm actually logged in.  Is there a way around this (I sort of assume it's by design)?

Answer (score 0):

> but it won't let me copy / paste until I'm actually logged in. Is
> there a way around this (I sort of assume it's by design)?

I have a Hyper-V machine here (Windows 10 Host, Kali Linux Guest), Enhanced Mode is enabled and ON, and I have to log in first before copy / paste. So it appears to be as it was designed.

I am using KeePass as the Password Manager on the Host machine.

Windows Updates affect Hyper-V so it may change down the road.